# Problem with a title background not showing

Tags: html, css, z-index

i am trying to have a yellow background of a title above an image. The text is fine but not the yellow color. It appears well if i put some margin on the image

Thanks all

https://codepen.io/pg2777/pen/oNNErMw

```
<article id="post-106" class="post-106 post type-post status-publish 
format-standard has-post-thumbnail hentry category-news">
               <img width="810" height="520" 
src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2019/07/21/07/12/new-york- 
4352072_960_720.jpg" class="attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail 
wp-post-image" alt=""          <header class="entry-header 
article_news_header">
                    <h1 class="entry-title">This is a header and 
it&rsquo;s here to do the show </h1>
                </header>
                <div class="entry-content">
                    <p>And this is the subheader excerpt. And this is the 
subheader excerpt. And this is the subheader excerpt. And this is the 
subheader excerpt.</p>

                </div>
            </article>

 .article_news_header{
    background-color:#ffe400;
    margin-top:-50px;
    z-index:9;
    width:30%;

}
.category-news img{
    border:11px solid purple;
    z-index:3;
    margin-left:40px;
}


.entry-title {

    font-size: 28px;
    margin-top:-30px;
    background-color:yellow;
    margin-bottom:80px;
    width:20%;
    color:red;
    z-index:6;
    height:100px;
}
```

Comment: `z-index` works with positioning (`position:relative`) to the element,  add that and it works.

Comment: Do u want the yellow bg over the image in bottom left side?

Comment: Use (position: relative) to .entry-title class. This will fix your issue.

Answer (score 2):

Add `position: absolute;` on `.entry-title`

```
.entry-title {
    font-size: 28px;
    margin-top:-30px;
    background-color:yellow;
    margin-bottom:75px;
    width:20%;
    color:red;
    z-index:6;
    height:100px;
   position: absolute;
}
```

Hope can help you

Comment: Glad to help you..!

Answer (score 0):

Read about [z-index](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp)

> The **z-index** property specifies the stack order of an element.
>
> An element with greater stack order is always in front of an element
>   with a lower stack order.
>
> *Note:* **z-index** only works on **positioned elements** (position: absolute,
>   position: relative, position: fixed, or position: sticky).

`z-index` works with positioning (`position:relative`) to the element, add it and should work.

Answer (score 0):

add this style

```
.entry-title {
font-size: 28px;
background-color:yellow;
width:20%;
color:red;
z-index:6;
height:100px;
position:absolute;
top:0px;
left:300px;
text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add (at the end) the position to the entry-title as relative,

```
.entry-title{
    ....
    ....
    position: relative;
}
```

**verified in your codepen also.**

Answer (score -1):

Add `position: relative;` on `.entry-title`

```
.entry-title {
    font-size: 28px;
    margin-top: -30px;
    background-color: yellow;
    margin-bottom: 80px;
    width: 20%;
    color: red;
    z-index: 6;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
}
```